# Uniform convergence of $\frac{\sin^2(nx)}{n\sin(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> How to show $u_n(x)=\dfrac{\sin^2(nx)}{n\sin(x)}$ converges uniformly

**Attempt :**

Let $\varepsilon >0$, and this interval $[\varepsilon, \pi-\varepsilon]$

Then $\forall x\in[\varepsilon, \pi-\varepsilon], \quad \dfrac{\sin^2(nx)}{n\sin(x)}\le \dfrac{1}{n\varepsilon}$ hence $u_n(x)\overset{\text{unif.}}{\longrightarrow}0$ on $[\varepsilon, \pi-\varepsilon]$

We consider now $C(t):=\dfrac{\sin t}{t}$

Then we have $u_n(x)=\sin(nx)C(nx)$, and since $|C(nx)|\le1$

We have $|\sin(nx)C(nx)|\le|\sin(nx)|\le |nx|$

We can conclude that : $|x|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{n}\implies |u_n(x)|<\varepsilon$ 
and

$u_n(x)\overset{\text{unif.}}{\longrightarrow}0$ on $\left[0, \dfrac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)$

Now I 've got a gap for  $x\in \left[\dfrac{\varepsilon}{n},\varepsilon\right)$, which $u_n(x)$ doesn't seem to converge uniformly, May you confirm please?

Comment: What interval do you want to show it on?

Comment: I would like on $\mathbb{R}$, but at first I took this interval $[0,\pi]$

Comment: And $u_n(0)$ and $u_n(\pi)$ are not defined?

Comment: yes but for n fixed, $u_n(x)\underset{x\to 0}{\to}0$

Comment: ok understood thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniform convergence fails on $(0,\pi).$ Suppose otherwise. It should be clear that the pointwise limit of the $u_n$'s is $0$ on this interval. Thus $u_n \to 0$ uniformly on $(0,\pi).$ That implies $\sup_{(0,\pi)} u_n \to 0.$ However, letting $x_n=1/n,$ we see

$$\sup_{(0,\pi)} u_n \ge \frac{\sin^2 (nx_n)}{n\sin x_n} = \frac{\sin^2 (1)}{n\sin (1/n)} \to \sin^2 (1)>0.$$ That's a contradiction, proving the result.